# How to calculate standard error of estimate in deming regression?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, standard-error

I have calculated regression parameters using deming regression with the `mcreg` package:

```
dem.reg <- mcreg(x, y, method.reg="Deming")
printSummary(dem.reg)
```

Does anyone know how I can calculate standard error of the estimate?

Comment: I suggest using the deming package. See there: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/174549/11849

Answer (score -1):

According to the `mcr` package description, standard error seems not to be available directly. So in such case, you have to recalculate and rewriting a specific function following the principles described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Corrected_sample_standard_deviation)

If we take the example in `mcreg` function description, we have:

```
# requirements
library("mcr")
data(creatinine,package="mcr")
x <- creatinine$serum.crea
y <- creatinine$plasma.crea

# Deming regression fit.
# The confidence intercals for regression coefficients
# are calculated with analytical method
model1<- mcreg(x,y,error.ratio=1,method.reg="Deming", method.ci="analytical",
               mref.name = "serum.crea", mtest.name = "plasma.crea", na.rm=TRUE)

# Results
printSummary(model1)
getCoefficients(model1)
plot(model1)
```

which gives the following outputs and figure:

```
# ------------------------------------------
#   
#   Reference method: serum.crea
# Test method:     plasma.crea
# Number of data points: 108
# 
# ------------------------------------------
#   
#   The confidence intervals are calculated with analytical method.
# Confidence level: 95%
# Error ratio: 1
# 
# ------------------------------------------
#   
#   DEMING REGRESSION FIT:
#   
#   EST         SE        LCI        UCI
# Intercept -0.05891341 0.04604315 -0.1501984 0.03237162
# Slope      1.05453934 0.03534361  0.9844672 1.12461148
# NULL
```

[image: Deming regression results]

So you have your intercept & slope, as written into the graphic and you just have to code the `standard.error` calculation as follows for instance:

```
f.reg <- function(x){
  y <- x * 1.05453934 - 0.05891341 
  return(y)
}
y.hat <- f.reg(x)
n.items <- length(y.hat)
# please note that y has 'NA' values so you have to filter them 
standard.error <- sqrt(sum((y[ !is.na(y)]-y.hat[ !is.na(y)])^2)/n.items)
# > standard.error
# [1] 0.1566329
```

Comment: Please provide a reference for your formula. It looks a bit like the residual standard error of OLS regression (although you would divide by the degrees of freedom for an unbiased estimate).

Comment: @Roland: I already provided links at the beginning of my post, pointing to wikipedia definitions. In fact, it's the formula of uncorrected sample standard error that is commonly used. I put there an additional link to Wolfram's article on this topic: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StandardError.html

Comment: OK, and IMO that's not correct for OLS (see equation 2.23 [there](http://biocomp.cnb.csic.es//~coss/Docencia/ADAM/Sample/Simple%20Regression.pdf)) and definitely not correct for Deming regression. More importantly, this is not the "standard error of the estimate" (though it is not clear which estimate OP means there).

Comment: @Roland: Thanks for for the doc and I agree with you that I replied too quickly. From you opinion (and for my information), what would be the appropriate approach with Deming regression?

Comment: I believe you should bootstrap or jackknife methods with Deming regression.

Comment: I have to do method comparison. Literally saying I am interested in standard error for the estimate: Syx ≤10% of the average

Comment: @MaueMi "standard error for the estimate" Estimate of what?